# Excel Locate Next open cell and input today's date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have a spreadsheet I'm using to track train crossings near my work building for a project. Up until now, whenever I hear a train go by I open the sheet, go to the next available row, and input the date in column A, and the time in column B. I am keeping them separate because I will be plotting train crossings at different times during the day against the time of year. What VBA code can I use to locate the next row that is open, then add current date to column A and current time to column B? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim n As Long
    n = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Cells(n, 1).Value = Date
    Cells(n, 2).Value = Time
End Sub
```